# Datepicker in a form

Tags: javascript, php, datepicker

I have a simple form for registration. I have two problems: 
- The first one about the the  datepicker. I don't understand why it doesn't work, 
when I click in the space for the date the datepicker does not appear

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="invia")
{
  $titolo = addslashes($_POST['titolo']);
  $testo = addslashes($_POST['testo']);
  $str_data = strtotime($_POST['data']);
  include 'config.php';
  $sql = "INSERT INTO appuntamenti (titolo,testo,str_data ) VALUES ('$titolo', '$testo', '$str_data')";
  if($result = pg_query($sql))
  {
    echo "Inserimento avvenuto con successo.<br>
    Vai al <a href=\"index.php\">Calendario</a>";
  }
}else{
  ?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Titolo:<br>
<input name="titolo" type="text"><br>
Testo:<br>
<textarea name="testo" cols="30" rows="8"></textarea><br>
Date:<br>
<input name="datepicker" type="text" ><br>
Time:<br>
<input name="hour" type="time" ><br> 
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="invia">
</form>
</body>

  <?php
}
?>
```

> EDIT

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    $(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();

  $('.timepicker').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
    interval: 60,
    minTime: '8',
    maxTime: '08:00pm',
    defaultTime: '11',
    startTime: '08:00',
    dynamic: false,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true
  });


});
  </script>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="invia")
{
  $titolo = addslashes($_POST['titolo']);
  $testo = addslashes($_POST['testo']);
  $str_data = strtotime($_POST['data']);
  include 'config.php';
  $sql = "INSERT INTO appuntamenti (titolo,testo,str_data ) VALUES ('$titolo', '$testo', '$str_data')";
  if($result = pg_query($sql))
  {
    echo "Inserimento avvenuto con successo.<br>
    Vai al <a href=\"index.php\">Calendario</a>";
  }
}else{
  ?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Titolo:<br>
<input name="titolo" type="text"><br>
Testo:<br>
<textarea name="testo" cols="30" rows="8"></textarea><br>
<!--Data:<br>
<input name="datepicker" type="text" ><br>
Orario:<br>
<input name="hour" type="time" ><br> 
-->


Date:<br>
<input name="datepicker" id="datepicker" type="text"><br> Orario:
<br>
<input name="hour" type="text" class="timepicker"><br>



<input name="submit" type="submit" value="invia">
</form>
</body>

  <?php
}
?>
```

- Then I would have a similar datepicker to the time but with personalize hours ( for example in a range from 8.00 am to 8.00 pm ) how can i do?
  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do not loaded proper datepicker.js file

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: @Sinto yes how can i solve in your opinion?

Comment: @marcogomes datapicker doesn't appear when i click on data field

Comment: Can you able to use jQuery?

Comment: @Keyz23 and when you click doesn't show a error message in the console ?

Comment: @Sinto Not a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `jQuery`, then try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();

  $('.timepicker').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
    interval: 60,
    minTime: '8',
    maxTime: '08:00pm',
    defaultTime: '11',
    startTime: '08:00',
    dynamic: false,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
Date:<br>
<input name="datepicker" id="datepicker" type="text"><br> Orario:
<br>
<input name="hour" type="text" class="timepicker"><br>
```

Comment: Thanks you!! I update the first post, there's something wrong in my code because nothing change!

Comment: i have tried to write in an external file .js e load it but it doesn't change